# Symbolic computation of a region boundary

Tags: regions

Consider the three disk regions plotted here, where of course I had to set a single radius (scale) to make an actual plot:

[image]

But in my actual problem, the scale is not set.  For instance, we can set the radius of the large green disk to be $x>0$, and without loss of generality place its center at the origin.

I'm interested in the area of the dark orange wedge, as well as the length of its perimeter.

Thus I define the regions symbolically as follows:

```
\[ScriptCapitalR]left = Disk[{0, x/2}, x/2];
\[ScriptCapitalR]top = Disk[{x/2, x}, x/2];
\[ScriptCapitalR]big = Disk[{0, 0}, x];
\[ScriptCapitalR]goal = 
  RegionDifference[
   RegionIntersection[\[ScriptCapitalR]top, \[ScriptCapitalR]big], \
\[ScriptCapitalR]left];
Assuming[x > 0, RegionMeasure[\[ScriptCapitalR]goal]]
```

I get the RegionMeasure (i.e., area) just as I seek... in terms of $x$:

$$\frac{1}{8} x^2 \left(-2+\pi -\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{44}{117}\right)\right)$$

Fine.

Now I try to find its perimeter.  First I define its boundary:

```
\[ScriptCapitalR]goalBoundary = 
  Assuming[x > 0, RegionBoundary[\[ScriptCapitalR]goal]];
```

Now, I try to find the length of its perimeter:

```
ArcLength[\[ScriptCapitalR]goalBoundary]
```

or

```
RegionMeasure[\[ScriptCapitalR]goalBoundary]
```

and I get no answer.

However, if I set a particular value for $x$, I get the perimeter fine:

```
ArcLength[\[ScriptCapitalR]goalBoundary] /. x -> 1
```

$$\frac{1}{4} \left(\pi +2 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)+4 \sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)\right)$$

(Of course I can plot and visualize the boundary only if I set a value for $x$, as in:  `RegionPlot[\[ScriptCapitalR]goalBoundary /. x -> 1]`.  Again, fine.)

***How do I compute the perimeter symbolically for arbitrary $x>0$?***

Of course I could solve for $x \to 1$ and then exploit my knowledge that the perimeter scales as $x$, but I'm looking for a more general solution (applicable to other problems) that relies on symbolic computation, not my "human understanding" of dimensional scaling.

Comment: What version are you running? in 12.3 your successful call to `ArcLength` returns a machine number `2.034443787674293`.

Comment: I'm running 11.3.  Nevertheless, your answer does not address my core problem:  You certainly assume $x \to 1$, which works fine for me too.  What is your answer *FOR ARBITRARY* $x$?  Your answer *must* have an $x$ somewhere in it.  See?

Comment: Correct, I had just noticed the discrepancy when running your examples.

Comment: Since the top and left disks are the same size, the perimeter of the $R_{goal}$ is the same as the perimeter of $R_{big}\cap R_{top}$, if that helps.  To see this, look at the boundary of $R_{left}\cap R_{top}$.

Comment: This is more of a workaround. Sometimes when I can't get a symbolic answer out, I'll substitute a mathematical constant for a variable, run the calculation, then sub back. This of course does not guarantee the result is correct for all $x$ in your domain, but in a pinch it can work. `(ArcLength[\[ScriptCapitalR]goalBoundary] /. x -> EulerGamma) /. EulerGamma -> x`. You also need to be sure that your constant won't show up in the answer naturally, otherwise the backsub is wrong.

Comment: @ChipHurst:  Gee.  I never thought of that, but I must say it seems *so* kludgy.  Surely there is a better way... no?  After all, the area calculation worked fine.

Comment: @LouisB:  Nice insight based on reflection symmetry.  Alas, *Mathematica* still cannot compute the boundary of your smarter (simpler) equivalent region.

Comment: I think in general finding area an easier problem than finding arclength. It will usually be the case that integrating $\sqrt{1 + f'(x)^2}$ will be harder than integrating just $f(x)$. Compare `Area[Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {a, b}]]` and `Perimeter[Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {a, b}]]`. The elliptic integral functions were invented as a way to express the arclength of an ellipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular example expressing the region as [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) returns an arclength.

One such way to find defining implicit conditions for a region is through [`RegionMember`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html). Unfortunately it does not know the conditions for the boundary of our region:

```
RegionMember[\[ScriptCapitalR]goalBoundary, {a, b}] // Head
```

> ```
> (* RegionMember *)
> ```

However there's a trick to find the implicit boundary of a semialgebraic region. Find the implicit representation of the region itself and then find its boundary through [CylindricalDecomposition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CylindricalDecomposition.html).

```
Rcond = RegionMember[\[ScriptCapitalR]goal, {a, b}];

Rbdcond = CylindricalDecomposition[Rcond, {x, b, a}, "Boundary"];

Rimplicit = ImplicitRegion[Rbdcond, {a, b}];
```

And the arclength, which comes back after some time on my machine:

```
Assuming[x > 0, ArcLength[Rimplicit]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {17.7282, x ArcTan[4/3] + x ArcTan[2]}
> ```

Comment: Oh hey... wonderful.  Thanks so much for working on this.  This is the second time I've been "saved" by `CylindricalDecomposition` this week, and I hadn't heard of it before.  I confess I really don't understand it... and the documentation could be clearer.  But it works, and most importantly is of the style and constraints I laid out.  Very helpful.  Bravo.  ($\checkmark$)

Comment: Now I get it.  Now I get it.  A very powerful function.  I will use `CylindricalDecomposition` a lot now.  Basically:  given an inequality, break it into inequalities for each of the variables, as will be useful in lots of multi-dimensional integrals.

Comment: Correct, and described formally at this bullet here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CylindricalDecomposition.html#1067943069

Comment: Yes, I had read that bullet, but (since you're at WRI) I must say it could have been explained better.  Why is it called *CYLINDRICAL*Decomposition, after all?  I only understood it from working through the examples.  You could add examples where a region is defined by intersecting disks, or rectangles, then gets converted fully to an integral over the region.  Anyway, a very useful function.  Thanks to all the mathematicians and coders who brought it to us.

Comment: (Was at wri). That’s the nomenclature for problem, but it’s referring to a more general type of cylinder. That part of the name confused me at first too. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_set

Answer (score 1):

We want to calculate the arc length of the path along A-B-C-A.  There are two paths from C to A.  Both paths have the some length, so we choose the one along the top circle.  We first calculate the length of the chord from A to B.  The chord length is used calculate the arc length from A to B along the big circle and the arc length from B to A along the top circle.  The left disk is not used in this solution.

[image]

The easy way to get the coordinates of B is to reflect A across the line from the center of the big circle to the center of the top circle.  The formulas for the arc length and included angle are from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment).  $\theta_1$ is the central angle of the top circle subtended by the chord $A B$.    $\theta_2$ is the central angle of the big circle subtended by the chord $A B$.

[image]

Here is the calculation:

```
cTop = {x/2, x};
v1 = Simplify[Normalize[cTop], x > 0] ;
v2 = RotationTransform[π/2][v1] ;
ptA = {0, x} ;
ptB = ReflectionMatrix[v2].ptA;
chord = Simplify[Norm[ptB - ptA], x > 0];
θ1 = 2 ArcSin[chord/(x)];
s1 = x θ1/2;
θ2 = 2 ArcSin[chord/2/x];
s2 = x θ2;
perimeter = s1 + s2
perimeter /. x -> 1.0
```

The resulting arc length is $$x \sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)+2 x \sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)$$

Code for the graphics follows

```
With[{x = 1}, Graphics[{{Opacity[.1], Blue, Disk[{0, x/2}, x/2],
    Orange, Disk[{x/2, x}, x/2], Green, Disk[{0, 0}, x]},
   {Red, Text["A", {0, x}],
    Text["B", {4 x/5, 3 x/5}],
    Text["C", {x/2, x/2}]}},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 3/2}}, Axes -> True,
  ImageSize -> Small, Frame -> True]
 ]

disks = {Opacity[.2], Green, Disk[{0, x/2}, x/2],
   Disk[{x/2, x}, x/2], Disk[{0, 0}, x]};
lines = {Black, Line[{{0, 0}, {x/2, x}}], Dashed,
   Line[{{0, x}, {2 x, 0}}]};
points = {PointSize[.015], Red, Point[ptA], Magenta, Point[ptB]};
vectors = {Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, v1/2}], Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0}, v2/2}]};

Graphics[{disks, lines, vectors, points} /. x -> 1,
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {0, 3/2}}, Axes -> True,
 GridLines -> {Range[-1, 2, .5], Range[0, 1.4, .2]},
 ImageSize -> Medium, Frame -> True]
```

Comment: What is `pt1`?  And did you include all *three* arcs?  I don't see that.

Comment: Show be `ptA`.  I'll fix it.  -- Done!

Comment: Your result agrees with mine (for $x \to 1$) so I trust you're correct.  Thanks ($+1$).  But as I wrote I was hoping to leverage the symbolic manipulation "smarts" of *Mathematica* rather than do most of the analysis "by hand" and then just implement it in *Mathematica*.  After all, that works fine for the area.  I still don't understand why it doesn't work for perimeter.  And I want to easily compute other measures, such as the wedge region's center of mass, without having to go through the traditional calculations I would without the benefit of Mathematica.  Let's see if someone figures it.